# How to get file extension while using vue-picture-input

Tags: file-upload, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Now I succeeded to upload picturefiles using vue-picture-input and put it into s3 via apigateway.Based on the original document, the name of file should be determined by myself, but I have no info of the file extension of the file that user uploaded. Below is the code I wrote.

onChange function accept the prop "image" so I checked whether there's extension info, but I failed. Actually in the image binary data, extension is fixed as jpeg, even if the original file extension is others like png or jfif. please let me know hot to get the original file extension while using vue-picture-input

```js
   async onChange (image) {
      console.log('New picture selected!')
      if (image) {
        //I tried to extract extension from Image, but this "ext" is always "jpeg".
        var ext= image.substr(image.indexOf("/",0)+1,image.indexOf(";",0)-image.indexOf("/",0)-1)
        var formData = new FormData();
        console.log('Picture loaded.')
        this.image = image
        formData.append("test"+ext, image);
        var url="url"+"test"+ext;
        const result = await this.$axios.$put(url, formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
              'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PUT',
            }
        })
      } else {
        console.log('FileReader API not supported: use the <form>, Luke!')
      }
    },
```

Comment: Now I understood the data is encoded with base64. the above question is based on my misunderstanding. so I discard this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `discard`?